# Change window decoration for XFCE + Ubuntu

Tags: debian

I have installed debian 9 with xfce and compiz. How can I change the theme of gtk-window-decorator?

If I understand correctly gtk-window-decorator uses metacity's configuration. So far I have my ~/.themes directory with a few entries in it but I don't know how to activate them. All I could find with search engines is that I should use gnome-tweak-tool but that doesn't work, because it is for gnome3. I also thought of using gconf-editor and somehow find the key for the current theme's name but it is completely empty.

I am not married to gtk-window-decorator, I would use emerald if I could but that does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, there might be multiple answers that depends on metacity and compiz versions you have... Please try to change theme using this command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "THEME_NAME"`

**UPDATE 1:**
You need to install `libmetacity`! gtk-window-decorator use library from metacity to draw window decorations. Otherwise gtk-window-decorator use default / builtin cairo theme.

**UPDATE 2:**
Oh, it seems that gtk-window-decorator is [built without metacity](https://salsa.debian.org/compiz-team/compiz/commit/c36fa3cf661eb363f75ca54fe642bad0f0377f40).
Debian should update compiz or simply add patches that adds support for libmetacity 3.22.

**UPDATE 3:**
For everyone! If you have any problems changing theme in gtk-window-decorator and/or metacity please read this [post](https://www.patreon.com/posts/metacity-theme-12126230).

**UPDATE 4:**
Compiz in debian currently needs 4091 - 4094 and 4102 revisions from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~compiz-team/compiz/0.9.13/changes/4121?start_revid=4121) to enable Metacity theme support. Remove `-DBUILD_METACITY=OFF` and then rebuild when required revisions are added.

Comment: Unfortunately it has no effect. If I read it back using `gsettings get ...` it retains the value but compiz does not care about it. I don't actually have metacity installed, gtk-window-decorator reads metacity settings.
This is compiz 0.9.13.0 from the debian 9 repo.

Comment: Please post output of `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.

Comment: it says: `XFCE`

Comment: Just to be sure I've installed libmetacity1 but no change.

Comment: You need to rebuild compiz with metacity theme support enabled, otherwise it will not work, sorry!

Comment: Ok I will try to recompile later, but do you have any idea why it was disabled in the first place? If I remove `-DBUILD_METACITY=OFF` would that have any side effects? The changelog says, the metacity bump made some stuff private, I don't know what that means.

Comment: If you use same version that debian has then it will not work. It was disabled because that version does not support libmetacity 3.22+. You can get patches / commits from upstream (launchpad.net). If you use IRC then you can find me in #gnome-flashback channel on irc.gnome.org in case you need more info / help.

Comment: Did you get themes working?

Comment: No, not yet. Changing compiz is the last resort for me. I will present my arguments as a bug report, see what those guys think about it, maybe give emerald another go.

Comment: You need 4091 - 4094 and 4102 revisions from [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~compiz-team/compiz/0.9.13/changes/4121?start_revid=4121). Remove `-DBUILD_METACITY=OFF` and then rebuild.

Comment: Thanks but I managed to compile emerald, for me that's an easier solution.

Comment: Maybe add your instructions about compiz into the response as update 4 so it's easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile Emerald which also provides nice decoration. Download it from here: https://github.com/compiz-reloaded/emerald

Under Debian, the dependencies are provided by these packages: libdecoration0-dev libwnck-3-dev intltool

Run this command in the unzipped Emerald directory to compile it, you may need to run it as root: `./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix /usr && make && make install`

Then set Emerald as the window decorator with `emerald --replace`. For those who want to use Metacity, see the other response from muktupavels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new and don't know a whole lot about Linux but I change my window decorations in Window Manager.

If Window Manager works for you then you also need to move all of your window decorations to `/usr/share/themes` in order to use them in Window Manager.